# PhpStorm-EAP: Sync changes made on remote server

Tags: phpstorm

When I create new file and tree structure on my remote server, how can I have it synchronized with PhpStorm-EAP ? Clicking on the synchronize button doesn't do anything (bug?).

Answer (score 1):

Just select the project root folder and click "Tools | Deployment | Download from %DeploymentConfiguration%".

[image]